# Export fbx from Maya to blender problem

Tags: .fbx

I have a really big scene in MAYA. It has almost 250 objects, each with a lot of polygons. Some are parented to the other. I want to export them into blender as FBX. So that I get the UVs from maya. Even though I have applied transformations (freeze transformations in maya), when I import the file in blender, many objects do not come in the file. When I open the same in maya, it works perfectly, i get all the objects. I am guessing I ma doing something wrong in blender. if anybody know anything about this, it would be a great help for me

Comment: The same fbx is opening perfectly on unreal engine too. Its just causing problem with blender

Comment: When importing, there are a bunch of options on the right of the popup windows. Make sure to check all the relevant ones. Also, after importing in blender, go to window / toggle system console and see if any error was printed